# How to create 2-layers neural network using TensorFlow and python on MNIST data

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I'm a newbie in machine learning and I am following tensorflow's tutorial to create some simple Neural Networks which learn the MNIST data.

I have built a single layer network (following the tutotial), accuracy was about 0.92 which is ok for me. But then I added one more layer, the accuracy reduced to 0.113, which is very bad.

Below is the relation between 2 layers:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

#layer 1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 100]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
y1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)

#layer 2
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y2 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2)

#output
y = y2
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
```

Is my structure fine? What is the reason that makes it perform so bad? How should I modify my network?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The input of the 2nd layer is the `softmax` of the output of the first layer. You don't want to do that.

You're forcing the sum of these values to be 1. If some value of `tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1` is about 0 (and some certainly are) the softmax operation is lowering this value to be 0. Result: you're killing the gradient and nothing can flow trough these neurons.

If you remove the softmax between the layers (but leve it the softmax on the output layer if you want to consider the values as probability)  your network will work fine.

Tl;dr:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

#layer 1
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 100]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
y1 = tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1 #remove softmax

#layer 2
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y2 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2)

#output
y = y2
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
```

Comment: Thank you @nessuno, you are right! Now I replace it by ReLU and it is working very well ^^

Answer (score 0):

Came into exactly the same problem, gradients diverged and got a bunch of `nan` for the predicted `y`. Implemented what suggested by nessuno, unfortunately, the diverging gradients still not fixed.

Instead I've tried `sigmoid` as the activation function for layer 1, it worked! But for `relu` didn't work if initiate `W1` and `W2` as zero matrices, accuracy is only 0.1135 . In order to make both `relu` and `sigmoid` work, better randomize the initialization of `W1` and `W2`. Here's the modified code

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

# layer 1
with tf.variable_scope('layer1'):
    W1 = tf.get_variable('w1',[784,200],
                         initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    b1 = tf.get_variable('b1',[1,],
                         initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    y1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)
#   y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1) # alternative choice for activation

# layer 2
with tf.variable_scope('layer2'):
    W2 = tf.get_variable('w2',[200,10],
                     initializer= tf.random_normal_nitializer())
    b2 = tf.get_variable('b2',[1,],
                         initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    y2 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2)

# output
y = y2
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
```

I found [this link](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/assignment1/assignment1_soln) is helpful, see question 2 part (c), which gives backpropagation derivatives for a basic 2-layer neural network. In my opinion, when users didn't specify any acivation function, just apply linear flow in layer 1, will end up with backprograting a gradient looks something like `(sth)*W2^T*W1^T`, and as we initilize both `W1` and `W2` to be zeros, their product is likely to be very small close to zero, which result in vanishing gradients.

**UPDATE**

This is from the Quora answer Ofir [posted](https://www.quora.com/What-are-good-initial-weights-in-a-neural-network) about good initial weights in a neural network.

> The most common initializations are random initialization and Xavier
>   initialization. Random initialization just samples each weight from a
>   standard distribution (often a normal distribution) with low
>   deviation. The low deviation allows you to bias the network towards
>   the 'simple' 0 solution, without the bad repercussions of actually
>   initializing the weights to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the code snippets above. Results below 90% was discarded and I never really felt sure I did what the comments above had. Here is my full code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

#layer 1
W1 = tf.get_variable('w1', [784, 100], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', [1,], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
y1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1) 

#layer 2
W2 = tf.get_variable('w2',[100,10], initializer= 
tf.random_normal_initializer())
b2 = tf.get_variable('b2',[1,], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
y2 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y1, W2) + b2)

#output
y = y2
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), 
reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(10000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: 
mnist.test.labels}))
```

By changing 10000 -> 200000 i reached 95,5%.

Comment: I worked a bit more and even repeating 95,5% was hard. This would be very nice of some professional could comment on. The result is way below the expected. The variations I've tried are the gradient parameter, number of repetitions, progressively reduces gradient parameter. Since there are close to 80000 variabels in the grid an almost perfect result is what I expected. I am aware about https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros but that includes a large number of insightful usages. To see something this simple corrected would help more for me anyway.

Comment: You can also achieve better results by initialising weights like that: `W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([784,100], -0.01, 0.01))`. Doesn't sound like much but initializing weights close to 0 actually helps in this case.

Comment: i think it peaks at 20k an two layer